# PKIX path building failed in Java 7 but not Java 8 - Cannot connect to my HTTPS server despite having a Let's Encrypt certificate trusted by browsers

Tags: java, ssl, https, java-7

I'm writing a desktop app which needs to download a few config files from my HTTPS only server which runs a valid Let's Encrypt certificate which is trusted in Chrome and Firefox, and Java 8. I want the app to be as compatible as possible so I am targeting Java 7 as a minimum. In Java 7 the app cannot connect with the error `Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

I've tried many solutions and this appears to be the closest to my problem:

["PKIX path building failed" despite valid Verisign certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041602/pkix-path-building-failed-despite-valid-verisign-certificate)

Unfortunately nothing appears wrong with my server and https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=baldeonline.com
shows that Java 7 SHOULD connect.

How would I use a different (or system) certificate store programmatically? Obviously it's not user friendly if the user has to dig around in their java installation folder so I'd want to make any changes with the program itself.

The function which raises the error:

````
        try {
            URL obj = new URL(urlPointer);
            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");//I have also tries TLSv1 but no difference 
            sslContext.init(null, null, new SecureRandom());
            con.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
            int responseCode = 0;
            try {
                responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            System.out.println("POST Response Code : " + responseCode);

            if (responseCode >= 400) {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        con.getErrorStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
                return response.toString();
            } else {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        con.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
                return response.toString();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        } catch (KeyManagementException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }

    }```
````

Comment: The problem looks like related to the fact that different JREs use different keystores. Try to use the same keystore as you use with JRE 8

Comment: Does Java 7 have the "DST Root CA X3" root certificate in its `jre/lib/security/cacerts` file? I bet not. If you are writing an app connecting to a specific website then you should be using certificate pinning anyway.

Comment: I've added to my original post - how would i go about implimenting this in the jar itself? I can't resonably expect the user to dig around in the jre.

Comment: Have a read of [this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning)

Comment: SSLLabs only checks if protocols and ciphersuites (and maybe other parameters like DHE or sigalgs) used by particular clients (like Java) are compatible to the server; it does not try to check the cert/chain against different truststores (which often can vary for the same software version). _Oracle_ Java 7 does not have the DST Root X3 used for LetsEncrypt until [7u111 which is paid-only](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/javase7supportreleasenotes-1601161.html#R170_111). _OpenJDK_ j7 probably varies depending on your environment or package. IBM I don't know.

Comment: Also note that LetsEncrypt plans to switch to their own root and _not_ the DST/IdenTrust root, although this plan was [recently delayed until next year](https://letsencrypt.org/2019/04/15/transitioning-to-isrg-root.html). If doing your own truststore you will need to include the ISRG root(s) when or before that happens.

Answer (score 0):

As I can't seem to find a good example anywhere online here's my general purpose solution to the problem. Use a bunch of root certificates stored INSIDE the jar file, and unzip them at run-time. Then use the certificates in a trust manager, replacing the old Java ones. Certificate Pinning is only an acceptable solution if you only want to connect to one server, this solution however should cover most of the internet. You'll need to get the root certificates from somewhere, I used the Windows Trust store to export X.509 base64 encoded certificates.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;

public class CertificateHandler {
    public String thisJar = "";

    public CertificateHandler() {
        try {
            thisJar = getJarFile().toString();
            thisJar = thisJar.substring(6).replace("%20", " ");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            thisJar = "truststore.zip";
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //truststore.zip is used in place of the jar file during development and isn't needed once the jar is exported
    }

    public static TrustManagerFactory buildTrustManagerFactory() {
        try {
            TrustManagerFactory trustManager = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            try {
                KeyStore ks;
                ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
                ks.load(null);
                File dir = new File(Launcher.launcherSafeDirectory + "truststore");
                File[] directoryListing = dir.listFiles();
                if (directoryListing != null) {
                    for (File child : directoryListing) {
                        try {   
                            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(child);
                            System.out.println("Trusting Certificate: "+child.getName().substring(0, child.getName().length() - 4));
                            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
                            X509Certificate caCert = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(is);
                            ks.setCertificateEntry(child.getName().substring(0, child.getName().length() - 4), caCert);
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
                            e2.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                trustManager.init(ks);
            } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            return trustManager;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static TrustManager[] getTrustManagers() {
        TrustManagerFactory trustManager = buildTrustManagerFactory();
        return trustManager.getTrustManagers();
    }

    public void loadCertificates() {
        try {
            UnzipLib.unzipFolder(thisJar, "truststore", Launcher.launcherSafeDirectory + "truststore");
            System.out.println("Extracted truststore to "+ Launcher.launcherSafeDirectory);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private File getJarFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
        String path = Launcher.class.getResource(Launcher.class.getSimpleName() + ".class").getFile();
        if(path.startsWith("/")) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("This is not a jar file: \n" + path);
        }
        path = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(path).getFile();
        return new File(path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf('!')));
    }
}
```

The code above handles creating a TrustManager[] array that can be used in HTTPS connections as follows:

```
private static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

static String sendPOST(String POST_URL, String POST_PARAMS, TrustManager[] trustManagers) {
    try {
        URL obj = new URL(POST_URL);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2"); 
        sslContext.init(null, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
        con.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

        // For POST only - START
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
        os.write(POST_PARAMS.getBytes());
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        // For POST only - END
        int responseCode = 0;

        try {
            //sendPOST("http://localhost", postParams);
            responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        System.out.println("POST Response Code : " + responseCode);

        if (responseCode >= 400) {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    con.getErrorStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
            return response.toString();
        } else {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
            return response.toString();
        }

    } catch (KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```